# How do I post my own app with facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have made an app and I want to create a UIButton that shares this app with facebook users.
I wrote the following code:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [controller setInitialText:@"My App Name"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/fruit-ninja-free/id403858572?mt=8/"]];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
else {

}
```

I've used an example URL of the famous fruit ninja cause my app is not yet on the app store and doesn't have it's own URL.

**The issue:**
If the app is not yet on iTunes, I don't have an iTunes URL to share yet... So how do I share my app?

Help is much appreciated...

Comment: Have you tried just sharing the url as just a string? It should detect that it's a url within Facebook (normally) and make it into a hyper-link

Comment: You can just post the link, Facebook will detect it and create a little card-preview similar.

Comment: Pass url as a string and facebook automatically detect it as a link

Comment: I don't understand your question. is your problem how to put your app's link _before_ you have a link to you app, or what exactly?

Comment: I thought my question was clear but apparently I was wrong :) I updated the question with "The issue:" part... Should be clearer now... By the way, holex, yes, this is my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create stub for your app at [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/). After that you'll be able to get link to your application even before submission.

[image: View in App Store]